# Using data.table to make summary table

Tags: r, data.table, summary

The working data looks like:

```
df <- data.table(Name = c("a","a","b","b","b","c","c"),
             SPP = c("YP","YP","YP","BY","BY","CY","YP"),
             Con = sample(1:20,7))
df
   Name SPP Con
1:    a  YP  18
2:    a  YP   4
3:    b  YP   2
4:    b  BY  15
5:    b  BY  17
6:    c  CY   1
7:    c  YP  20
```

The goal is to summarize information in `SPP` grouped by `Name`. The ideal output should looks like:

```
   Name SPP N V1
1:    a  YP 2  1
2:    b  YP 1  2
3:    b  BY 2  2
4:    c  CY 1  2
5:    c  YP 1  2
```

Where `N` is the number of observations for each `SPP` in each `Name` group. `V1` is the total number of `SPP` type in each `Name` group. For example, in the above summary table, row 2 and row3 shows that: **b**(`Name`) has 1 **YP** and 2 **BY** (`SPP`). The total `SPP` type in **b** is 2(`V1`).

I can generate the summary table by:

```
m1 <- df[, .(.N), by = .(Name, SPP)]
m2 <- df[,.(length(unique(SPP))), by = Name]
merge(m1,m2,by = c("Name"))
```

The question is whether I can generate this summary table using more concise `data.table` command(s) without using `merge` two tables? I tried something like:

```
m1 <- df[, .(.N, length(unique(SPP))), by = .(Name, SPP)]
```

It does not work well as wanted. I don't know why. Could someone help me to explain about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works, but is too convoluted in my opinion, with nested aggregation:

```
df[, c(.SD[, .N, by=SPP], n_SPP = uniqueN(SPP)), by=Name]
# or 
df[, {z = .SD[, .N, by=SPP]; c(z, n_SPP = nrow(z))}, by=Name]
```

Another option would be sequential aggregation:

```
df[, .N, by=.(Name, SPP)][, n_SPP := .N, by=Name][]
```

Comment: It definitely works well with chaining! I just curious whether I can find a single aggregation approach for further usage. I will wait a little bit to see anyone can provide other thoughts, if not, your answer will get my vote!  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, feel free to leave it open as long as you want. I'm also curious to see better approaches.

Comment: I've asked similar question to Matt in 2013. Just found the answer in old emails and it is much like your answer here :)